# How to develop javafx application for touch screen desktop?

Tags: java, javafx, touch, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am developing a javafx desktop application. Desktop machine is having a touch screen, no physical keyboard.

My queries are:

1. Will virtual keyboard automatically pop up or I have to do some extra settings?
2. How to scroll javafx stage up if keyboard pops up and slide down if keyboard is closed.
3. Any scene touch gesture  event to close keyboard?
4. how to catch touch event for button? will onaction handler handle touch actions 
   also?
5. how to catch touch event for textfield?
6. I don't have a testing machine? Is there any way to test all touch functions on my non-touch screen desktop using mouse? Or is it possible to run on android phone? or any other way?

I have gone through javafx documentation...but it is bit confusing..if i could get a sample application using buttons,textfields...I will get better understanding.

Your suggestions are important to me..please do share your views.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if rude, but first of all [read how and what to ask **here in StackOverflow**](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow) .Maybe you should go to https://stackexchange.com/

We are not a free-code service web. Here you can post your code and ask for help, but asking for a sample withouth providing effort from your side...difficult.

Comment: I am a newbie for javafx applications. I am definitely making efforts to get my thing done..I have already build my application for non-touch screen app. I want to modify it for touch screen . Since i don't have a testing machine to test my code, it has become difficult for me ...I am just asking if there are any extra steps for touch appp.
Regarding sample application,I am not asking for ready made code...just a reference application 
Acc to me, stack overflow helps clear your doubts regarding your code..

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/gestures.htm#JFXED166).